# "Dehydrated Japanese noodles under fluorescent lights" - Chandler from Friends

Tags: meaning-in-context

From Friends SS1.Ep8 (00:00)

> (Miss) : Hey, gorgeous. How's it going?
>
> Chandler : ***Dehydrated Japanese noodles under fluorescent lights***. Does
>   it get better than this?

What does Chandler mean when he responsed like that?

Comment: He's at work on a break. His dinner is instant noodles (likely microwaved) in a break room lit with harsh fluorescent lighting. Stuck at work with bad food in a bad atmosphere. He asks rhetorically "Does it get better than this?" with the ironic meaning of "You can't tell me how it could actually be worse."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He is being *sarcastic*.

Dehydrated noodles are a cheap, snack food - not exactly gourmet food. Likewise, fluorescent lights are often considered harsh, unpleasant lighting. They are usually found in places of business such as offices or stores as they are cheap and functional, certainly not 'mood' lighting.

He describes this mediocre food and atmosphere and then asks the rhetorical question "Does it get any better than this?" to sarcastically say that the situation is bad.